# How to register a SIP account with a specify network interface

Tags: c, ip, sip, voip, pjsip

I am using Pjsip library to register a Sip account to Sip server

```
/* Register to SIP server by creating SIP account. */
  {
 pjsua_acc_config cfg;
 
 pjsua_acc_config_default(&cfg);
 cfg.id = pj_str("sip:" SIP_USER "@" SIP_DOMAIN);
 cfg.reg_uri = pj_str("sip:" SIP_DOMAIN);
 cfg.cred_count = 1;
 cfg.cred_info[0].realm = pj_str(SIP_DOMAIN);
 cfg.cred_info[0].scheme = pj_str("digest");
 cfg.cred_info[0].username = pj_str(SIP_USER);
 cfg.cred_info[0].data_type = PJSIP_CRED_DATA_PLAIN_PASSWD;
 cfg.cred_info[0].data = pj_str(SIP_PASSWD);
 
  status = pjsua_acc_add(&cfg, PJ_TRUE, &acc_id);
  if (status != PJ_SUCCESS) error_exit("Error adding account", status);
 }
```

This working fine when my board only has one network interface, but when i run it on a new board which has many network interface, it always register to Server via interface have smalless IP address value. I read in this link: https://trac.pjsip.org/repos/wiki/FAQ#multihomed And realize that Pjsip always chooses a network interface to register by its algorithm. And i tried to bind my application to a newtork interface too like this: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/210982/bind-unix-program-to-specific-network-interface but it not work too. I need to choose network interface manually in the code, how can i do it ?

Answer (score 0):

Search for parameters named bound_addr in pjsip configuration - there should be (unless something changed with updates) one in transport configuration and one in rtp configuration. This is binding by interface address, not interface name, but it might be a starting point for modifications if necessary.